# error: expected unqualified-id before 'public'

Tags: c++

```
public class draw {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
     int draw (int i);
     for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
           cout << *;
           }
     }
}
```

I was looking to my homework which teacher wanted us to make a code which draws

```
*
**
***
****
...
```

It goes like that.

When I compiled it, It gives me an error `error: expected unqualified-id before 'public'`

I can't find a solution for it and I searched it for many times still no answer.

Comment: This code looks like a weird mix between Java and C++. Please figure out which language you're trying to use.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: ... dude, I just told you. Are you trying to write in Java or in C++?

Comment: You could read a C++ book, or search for examples of the correct way to use `public` in C++, or this page may be useful: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access

Comment: @aschepler Well, if it's supposed to be C++, then there shouldn't be any class at all.

Comment: True, that's only the beginning of how much is wrong with this code.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote isn't C++. Most of it looks like Java, actually.

Specifically:

```
public class draw {
     public static void main(String args[]) {
```

^ These two lines are Java.

```
     int draw (int i);
```

^ This line is C++ (I'm pretty sure Java doesn't let you declare functions like that).

```
     for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
```

^ This line could be either.

```
           cout << *;
```

^ The `cout <<` part is definitely C++, but the bare `*` is a syntax error in any language.

```
           }
     }
}
```

^ This last line (a `}` with no following `;` at the end of a class definition) is also Java, not C++.

---

To fix this, you need to actually write C++ code. I don't know where you got `public class draw` from, but a C++ version of this code would start like:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
```

Comment: in C/C++ function definitions have the opening curly brace in the first column, all alone one the line after the function name. The compiler doesn't care but the humans do. Rational: K&R

Comment: fair enough but, please explain. Why? For what it's worth, I upvoted your answer.

Comment: @BradS. How code is formatted depends on the author, not the language. You're trying to generalize indentation style across two languages (C, C++), when C alone has like 4 different major styles (and K&R isn't relevant to C++). None of my code has `{` on a separate line. What even is the point of your comment?

Comment: The point of my comment is that your answer gives a beautiful explanation which bits are C++, which are Java and which could be either but then you used an admittedly subtle Java-ism in your example C/C++ .  Don't like K&R, read Stroustrup.

Comment: @BradS. Ah. I didn't know you were referring to my sample code. In my case I wouldn't call it a Java-ism because this is simply how I've been formatting my code ever since I first learned C.

Answer (score -3):

You just add colon ' : ' after public keyword 
it should look like

```
public : 
yourFunction()
{
//loop
}
```

Comment: Did you miss the `public class draw` part?